# Lenovo laptop: Is it ok to leave the battery charging while it is being used?

Tags: laptop, battery, thinkpad, battery-life

Is it ok to leave the battery charging while it is being use? Or is it ok to keep the power plugged in with full charged battery while the laptop is in use? Can this shorten battery's lifespan?

Answer (score 3):

Most laptop batteries these days are Lithium Ion based - so constant charging won't hurt them.  This seems logical as most people don't even realise that battery care is even "a thing" let alone important.

Good tips for looking after a battery include:

- Avoid frequent complete discharge of a batter as contrary to popular belief, this can actually put strain on a lithium battery.
- Keep the battery and laptop cool.  No hotter than 95 degrees for an extended period of time.
- Consider removing the battery if you are planning to work the laptop hard on mains for an extended period of time
- Calibrate your battery and gauge by doing occasional (not frequent) full discharge/charge cycles
- Lithium batteries degrade over time - when buying a new battery for your laptop, buy a "new" battery - not one from old stock
- When storing the laptop unused for a long period of time, store it with some charge, but not full charge and do a calibration charge when you put it back into service.  Storing at 100% or empty is bad for the battery.  try storing at half charge or just below
- Look into buying high capacity batteries rather than spares - this can often server better.

Most important out of the above is to remember that heat destroys batteries a lot faster than a bad charge/discharge pattern.  Lithium batteries are "memory free" which means that charging from part-charged or not doesn't make much of an impact (if any) and most damage done over a long, bad charge/discharge life can be undone with a calibration or two.

[enter link description here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-extending-lithium-ion-battery-life/)  This document (although not the source for my info) contains mostly the same information and probably explains better than I could

Comment: Better yet: Avoid complete discharge (as in to 0%), totally. Even a single occurrence will greatly reduce the usable capacity. It’s also worth noting that there is no such thing as “constant charging”. When your battery is full, it will stop charging until drained to a certain value. Frequently, it’s set to 96%.

Comment: definitely Daniel - thanks for pointing this out, but if it happens as a one off - I wouldn't be too worried about the impact this will have over the whole lifespan of the battery

Comment: Well, I lost roughly 13% capacity when the battery died while my notebook was in standby mode. I don’t recommend it. :)

Comment: "*Consider removing the battery if you are planning to work the laptop hard on mains for an extended period of time*" This recommendation is obsolete. For modern laptops, the recommendation is the opposite -- the battery should always be left in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the source for this particular information, but I've been told that the best way to store a (e.g. laptop) battery is to keep it at 75%.

Now, a laptop and the battery, when charging and being used, heat up quite a bit. A batteries lifetime will decrease when it's being held in suboptimal conditions, so it might be a good idea to keep the battery out of the laptop when using it on AC for prolonged times.

If the 75%-Information is still, or ever was accurate, I can't tell, it's up to you how you use it. For the heat issue, I can refer you to these two links at least: [Link1](http://www.pcworld.com/article/242799/should_i_remove_my_laptop_battery_to_increase_its_life_.html), [Link2](http://askleo.com/should-i-remove-the-battery-if-i-leave-my-laptop-plugged-in/)

As Link2 points out, some people prefer to keep it in as an USP (Uninterruptable Power Supply).

**Edit:** As for the 75%, the argument behind it is that it's not ideal to store any rechargable battery for prolonged periods of time at full capacity.

**Edit2:** Battery Charge Level Link [here](http://www.wired.com/2013/09/laptop-battery/)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. It is fine to leave the battery charging while it is being used. Myself and everyone at my company runs off full battery and keeps it plugged in all day. After 2+ years my battery is still fine and holds its charge for hours. I cant even tell the difference from when it was new.